# how to remotely setup powershell to accept Enter-PSSession

Tags: windows, powershell

I have some computers I'm trying to remotely execute powershell commands but I'm running into some snags. For one thing, the computers do not have Enable-PSRemoting enabled so I am unable to simply Enter-PSSession. I tried to run a powershell script through psexec but I have yet to Set-Execution Policy on the machine.

My thoughts were to execute a powershell logon script that accomplished this but before I tried this I was going to see if there were any other methods to enable-psremoting on a machine. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need script for that. :) Here is a little wrapper function I use for exactly that purpose:

```
function Enable-Remoting {
param (
    [Alias('CN')]
    $ComputerName
)
    psexec \\$ComputerName -s -h -d powershell Enable-PSRemoting -Force
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using psexec? In order to accomplish most of my remoting needs I use PDQ Deploy because the antivirus solution that is deployed blocks psexec.

Comment: nevermind, got it to work with PDQ Deploy. Didn't realize it'd be that easy. Thanks!